# Amazon product api in php

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I have a problem when trying to use Amazon product API.  I have all my credentials, but when I send a request I get a 503 Status code with description

> You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at
>   a slower rate

I have tried a library called apai-io link: https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io.

I have also tried this code: https://www.patchesoft.com/amazon-affiliate-api-php#fullcode.

The weird thing is that I am sending only one request, trying to find a product with a specific ID. I would really be grateful if someone could give me some instructions or more information.

Comment: There is no foreach or any loop?

Comment: No, nothing only one request.

Answer (score 1):

They are rate limiting the requests, see the discussion here

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=9

And the policy here is new for the efficiency guidelines

> Effective 23-Jan-2019, the request limit for each account is calculated based on revenue performance attributed to calls to the Product Advertising API (PA API) during the last 30 days.
>   Each account used for Product Advertising API is allowed an initial usage limit of 8640 requests per day (TPD) subject to a maximum of 1 request per second (TPS). Your account will receive an additional 1 TPD for every 5 cents or 1 TPS (up to a maximum of 10) for every $4320 of shipped item revenue generated via the use of Product Advertising API for shipments in the last 30 days.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html#efficiency-guidelines

This has impacted me too and it's counterintuitive imo, you have to sell to use API but cannot use the API if you don't sell.